# How to properly exit grunt watch under yeoman

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I am running `grunt serve` and when it exits and I try to run it again the port is taken and it won`t run. How do I exit so that the port is not taken?

I am trying out yeoman and I am not familiar to the tools it uses.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the grunt livereload server, that has newer given me that problem that it would not release the port.